# Serial - cannot control servo from c++

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port, servo

I would like to ask about my program. I program to show sensor data yaw, pitch from oculus on C++ VS2013 then i send the data using serialport to arduino (parsing). The servo not moving but RX in my arduino already blinking when serial begin. 
this is my program c++:

```
int PITCH = (-1)*(int)RadToDegree(pitch) + 75;
int YAW = (int)RadToDegree(yaw) + 90;
char bintang[10] = { "*" }, koma[5] = { "," }, pagar[5] = { "#" }, kirim[10]; //out_p[10];
SerialPort arduino(port_name);
if (arduino.isConnected()) { wzPrintf(20, 130, "Connection Established"); }
else wzPrintf(20, 130, "ERROR, check port name");
sprintf_s(kirim,"%c%3d%c%3d%c", bintang,YAW,koma,PITCH,pagar);
    arduino.writeSerialPort(kirim, strlen(kirim));
```

and this is my arduino program (parsing)(*(data yaw),(data pitch)#):

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

int serv;
Servo myServo1,myServo2;

int j,i;
boolean stringComplete=false,rxSerial=false;
String inputString="";
String data[100];

void setup() {

for(int i=2;i<=7;i++){

pinMode(i,OUTPUT);

}

myServo1.attach(9);
myServo1.write(90);

Serial.begin(115200);
delay(2000);

}

void loop() 
{

if(Serial.available()){

char inChar=Serial.read();

if(inChar=='#'){

  rxSerial=false;

  stringComplete=true;

}

if(rxSerial){

  inputString+=inChar;

}

if(inChar=='*'){

  rxSerial=true;

 }

 }

 if(stringComplete){


j=0;

data[j]="";

for(i=0;i<inputString.length();i++){

  if ( inputString[i] == ','){

    j++;

    data[j]="";

  }

  else {

    data[j] += inputString[i];

  }

}


 // int servo1 = (data[0].toInt())-90;
  int servo1 = data[0].toInt();  
  if (servo1 <= -85) {
  servo1 = -85;
  }
  else if  (servo1 >= 85){
  servo1 = 85;
  }
 //servo1 = map(servo1, -90, 90, 0, 180);
int servo2 = data[1].toInt();



myServo1.write(servo1);
myServo2.write(servo2);

Serial.print(servo1);
Serial.print(",");
Serial.println(servo2);

inputString="";

stringComplete=false;

}

}
```

Comment: Why `char bintang[10] = { “*” }`? Why not `char bintang = ‘*’`?

Comment: it should have { }, but i already change " to ' there is not work at all. same previous.